# GridView paging not working proper

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, bind, paging

I'm trying to make paging with GridView,

and I have already added GridView's PageIndexChanging method,

but the second page returns an empty page.

What I'm doing wrong with this code ?

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has solved when I added this

```
private void FillGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = "Query..."
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

And changed :

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    FillGrid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       BindGrid();
    }
}
private void BindGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = "Query..."
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender,GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.BindGrid();
}
```