# Gridview pagination not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

While I am trying to implement paging for `gridview` i did it as shown below 
but when I click on page number the page not loading. No exception or error shows up?

I tried what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025739/gridview-paging-not-working-proper) but that is not working out.

Finally any code improvement in general? Can this be done in a better way ?

**code markup**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LoanReports.aspx.cs" Inherits="BankingDemo.LoanReports" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Banking Site (Demo)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" HeaderStyle-BackColor="CornflowerBlue" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" CellPadding="5" AllowSorting="True" A`enter code here`llowCustomPaging="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric">
             <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Continent" HeaderText="Continent" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Region" HeaderText="Region" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="SurfaceArea" HeaderText="SurfaceArea" />
<%--                 <asp:BoundField DataField="IndepYear" HeaderText="IndepYear" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="population" HeaderText="population" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="LifeExpectancy" HeaderText="LifeExpectancy" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="GNP" HeaderText="GNP" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="GNPOld" HeaderText="GNPOld" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="LocalName" HeaderText="LocalName" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="GovernmentForm" HeaderText="GovernmentForm" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="HeadOfState" HeaderText="HeadOfState" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Capital" HeaderText="Capital" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Code2" HeaderText="Code2" />--%>
             </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**c# code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.Types;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace BankingDemo
{
    public partial class LoanReports : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                get_table();
            }
        }
        private void get_table()
        {
            string ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnConfig"].ConnectionString;
            string cmdTxt = @"select Code,
                                     name,
                                     Continent,
                                     Region,
                                     SurfaceArea,
                                     IndepYear,
                                     population,
                                     LifeExpectancy,
                                     GNP,
                                     GNPOld,
                                     LocalName,
                                     GovernmentForm,
                                     HeadOfState,
                                     Capital,
                                     Code2
                                from world.country";

            try
            {
                using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnStr))
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmdTxt))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    using (MySqlDataAdapter myadapter = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        myadapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            myadapter.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `get_table()` - 1. breaks naming conventions. 2. tells code reader that it will return data table and won't bind the grid. I strongly feel there should be two methods, one that returns data (fetched from `DAL`) and other to bind that data to the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple solution, change PageIndexChanging method. Just call get_table() method in your code. Review your updated code.

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        get_table();
    }
```

Comment: yea you are right my friend i also figured out that today I just changed `GridView1.DataBind();` to `this.get_table_method();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebind Grid data source in `GridView1_PageIndexChanging` event handler. For that you need to refactor code a bit so that `get_table()` will return the `DataTable`. It should not bind data table to grid. `get_table()` is terrible name. Use `GetTable` or event better `GetCountries` instead.

So your new code looks like:

```
Page_Load(..) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        var dt = GetCountries();
        BindGrid(GridView1, dt);
    }
}

BindGrid(GridView grid, DataTable dt) {
    grid.DataSource = dt;
    grid.DataBind();
}

GetCountries() {
    // your get_table() code here
    return dt;
}

GridView1_PageIndexChanging(..) {
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    var dt = GetCountries();
    BindGrid(GridView1, dt);
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add GridView1 to the first call to BindGrid, in Page_Load.

Comment: @wazz thank you my friend ill try it now ... but from your experience is their any better way to do it ... the code now seems messy !

Comment: @wazz - Updated. Thanks.

Comment: @sam - `GetCountries` should not be in page. Countries should be returned by data access layer. Apart from that there's nothing much that you can remove from this page's code.